# AWS S3 new public bucket has over 3000 requests per day

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, web-traffic

I created a new (not even a week old) public S3-bucket to access some files remotely (it has to be public - that is the crux). Things like logging and versioning are deactivated, and pretty much all the standard options were kept.

However, I have a huge amount of requests per day (over 3000requests per day and maybe even increasing) that is not connected **at all** to my assessing of the files. Where does such a traffic come from? Does amazon access the files itself by default? Something like a tracking of the files? Can this be deactivated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can activate [Amazon S3 server access logging](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ServerLogs.html) to obtain this information. The logs will show the requests and their origin.

FYI, requests are charged at `$0.0004 per 1000`, therefore your 3000 requests per day are costing `1.2c per day`.